# Show that the series $\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{e^{-nwz}}{(w+n)^2}$ defines a holomorphic function.

Tags: sequences-and-series, complex-analysis

> Let $w=-1+i$. Show that the series
>
> $$\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{e^{-nwz}}{(w+n)^2}$$
>
> Defines an holomorphic function in $D=\{z \in \Bbb{C}:Re(z)+Im(z)<0\}$

So this question is supposed to be in the context of holomorphic (or meromorphic) sequences of functions. However I've been working with this kind of sequences for a while and I don't have the leastest idea of how to use the different results I proved in this kind of excercise. Where should I start from?

Comment: $D=\{z :Re(w z)>0$.  Show that the series converges uniformly on any compact subset of D.

Answer (score 0):

Hint: Fix a disc that stays away from the boundary of $D.$ How big can the $n$th summand be on such a disc? The Weierstrass M-test will be useful.